# Custom dropdown for specific relationship type

Tags: custom-fields, relationships

When creating a new relationship is it possible to create a dropdown that only displays when you have selected a specific relationship type.

For instance:
Add custom relationship “Representation”
Represented by [individual]
Representative of [individual]

Add custom dropdown “Representative Type”
- Publicist
- Manager
- Agent

When you go to add a relationship currently the Representation dropdown displays on all relationship types. I.e. “child of” displays representative type, clearly unnecessary. Is it possible to only display that dropdown when Representation is selected from the relationship type dropdown?

Thank you for your time and consideration,

Tim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create custom group of fields for a specific relationship with your custom relationship type filter. This custom field will only be visible when you select relationship type from the drop down

[image]

Cheers

Pradeep